# Remove the cache for a particular Twig file

Tags: theming, caching

I'm showing the name of the currently logged-in user in header, using `\Drupal::currentUser()->getUsername()`, but it's showing an already cached  page. I know I can disable the cache for a particular page using `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger()`, but this won't work with the header.html.twig file.

How can I achieve it without affecting the performance?

Comment: You haven't provided much information about how you're adding the username into your template. But you might be better putting your user content into a block and adding it into a region. That way with the relevant user cache tags/context on your block it will get cached per user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a cache context and a cache tag of the user:

```
$variables['username'] = [
  '#markup' => \Drupal::currentUser()->getUsername(),
  '#cache' => [
    'contexts' => [
      'user',
    ],
    'tags' => [
      'user:' . \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
    ],
  ],
];
```

You can add this directly in a preprocess hook, but then the rendered output will vary for each user. For large numbers of users you might want to put this in a lazy builder callback, which will then match the auto-placeholder conditions and can be lazy-loaded through BigPipe without affecting page load performance.

See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/auto-placeholdering

Comment: The cache metadata can be specified directly in Twig template.

`{{ {'#cache': {contexts: ['user'], [tags: 'user:' ~ user.id]} }}`