# Caching user profile image?

Tags: 8, caching

If I log in as User 1, i see user 1's profile picture. If I log in as User 2, I see user 2's profile picture. As expected. But after browsing a bit, User 2 would suddenly see User 1's profile picture.

This ONLY seems to happen on /forum (i use the standard drupal forum module).

And I use my .theme file to populat a variable as follows:

```
 $variables['current_user_profile_picture_medium'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('image_style')->load('medium')->buildUrl($pp);
```

Where $pp = public://someOrOtherProfilePic.png

And I use it in my template as follows:

```
{{ current_user_profile_picture_medium }}
```

So it would seem that the .theme file figures out it needs to user profile pic A, but then when User B logs in, it still shows pic A.

I think I am missing something about caching here. It would seem the .theme file is only getting the details once. So I went to look what php is being generated and found this:

```
echo $this->env->getExtension('Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension')->escapeFilter($this->env, $this->sandbox->ensureToStringAllowed($this->getAttribute(($context["user"] ?? null), "profile_picture_medium", [])), "html", null, true);
```

It seems to be getting confused with $context["user"] or not updating it or something.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction? What am I missing about caching/twig/templates?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

It seems I might be having similar issues to [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186575/twig-drupal-caching-and-dynamic-variables).

**UPATE 2**

Adding this to settings.php didn't help:

```
$settings['cache']['bins']['page'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

**UPDATE 3**

I tried adding a twig function, but even that remains cached. This doesn't seem to work:

```
<img src="{{ get_current_user_profile_picture() }}" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
```

If I put die() in this function, it doesn't hit the die() if the page has already been loaded once.

I'm really stumped....

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/282534/remove-the-cache-for-a-particular-twig-file

Comment: I solved this by replacing that part with a block instead of using the normal page.tpl file